# Xcode 4: how to implement game center achievements?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4, game-center, gamekit

I'm trying to include Achievements to my game, but the problem is that when I try them using GKTapper Apple Docs' example I'm not earning any achievement. For example: the first Ach. is earned when you tap 100 times a button. But when trying it on the simulator I don't earn this achievement.

CODE:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTapper/Introduction/Intro.html

From here I copied AppSpecificValues.h, GameCenterManager.h and .m

Then I declare them in my ViewController

and I use this to check the progress:

```
- (void) checkAchievements
{
    NSString* identifier = NULL;
    double percentComplete = 0;
    switch(self.currentScore)
    {
        case 10:
        {
            identifier= kAchievement10Taps;
            percentComplete= 100.0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(identifier!= NULL)
    {
        [self.gameCenterManager submitAchievement: identifier percentComplete:     percentComplete];
    }
}
```

And I finally try on the simulator, but as I said the Achievements don't progress.

What I am doing wrong??

Lots of thanks!!

If it is useful I read how to do that here:

Part1: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-game-center-achievements-and-leaderboards-part-1/

Part2: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-game-center-achievements-and-leaderboards-part-2/

Comment: Check if you are signed into GameCenter and your local player is authenticated. Also I hope your iTunes Connect is correctly configured.

Comment: Yes it is correctly authenticated

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your doing it right, so until you provide me with more info on whats wrong with your code, debugger output, etc.

Notes: In case you don't include lines: `default: break;` in your switch statement, add them.

How about some good links if they can help you.

**A tutorial for game center achievements is [right here.](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-game-center-achievements-and-leaderboards-part-1/)**

You should look at this tutorial from [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com) for creating GameCenter games:

The first part of the tutorial is [right here.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12) The source code project download is at the bottom.

The second part of the tutorial is [right here.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3325/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-22) The source code project download is at the bottom.

*Edit, that means you haven't implemented some of the methods in the tutorials, the methods work together and you don't have all the pieces.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will try your tutorials and see if I can solve that.

Comment: The first tutorial is what I used, and the second does not explain GC achievements. but thanks for helping

Comment: ooh! I have just noticed that the console gives me a log: "Missed Method" any ideas??